# What statistical test uses statsmodel to calculate significance?

Tags: statistics, statsmodels

I need to say in a report the type of correlation test I performed to the data. I used statsmodel to fit a quadratic equation but I can't seem to find what statistical test does statsmodel use to calculate the p-value (ANOVA?).

I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Wanna post your code?

Comment: There are several tests implemented in statsmodels. Without knowing what you used, it will not be possible to tell which test it is.